# How to keep components like button displayed while fetching array of data from database

Tags: react-native

I need help in displaying components like action button and search bar while fetching data from database. The components appear only after the data as been fetched successfully.

Is there a way to keep displaying the search and action component while fetching the data? And keep them visible after the data is fetched either successfully or not?

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContent}>
            <Item>                    
                <Input style={styles.searchinput} placeholder="Search Deals" value={this.state.search} onChangeText={this.browse} />
            </Item>

            <ScrollView>
                {deals.map(deal => (
                    <View style={styles.dealsContent} key={deal.id}>
                       ....
                    </View>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.addButton}
                    underlayColor='#ff7043' onPress={() => { console.log('pressed') }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 50, color: 'white' }}>+</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use Threading. Create new thread where you will fetch data, and on main thread you can show buttons and other controls while fetching data. You can find more on google about threads and how to use them.